# Open a file by file format with batch script

Tags: batch-file, java

So I am trying to open any file that ends with .jar with Java without having Java installed into windows, but a custom install path.
Currently my code looks like this which I also found on the web:

```
"C:\Users\pasi1\Desktop\Minecraft Sachen\MultiMc\Java Installs\jdk-17.0.3+7\bin\java.exe" -jar "files/OptiFine_1.19.2_HD_U_H9.jar"
```

Basically any .jar file in the folder "files" (only 1 file in that folder) should be started without having to know the specific name of that file, only by file extension. With the code above, I have to rename the file I have to open in the batch script every time, but it works that far.

I did find some scripts online but they all weren't able to open the file correctly (didn't open with Java).

Comment: What context? What have you tried already?

Comment: What platform? Have you assigned the correct app to open .jar files, or are you trying to bypass existing assignment?

Comment: `CD  "C:\Users\pasi1\Desktop\Minecraft Sachen\Optifine Installer\files"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('DIR /b *.jar') do (
    timeout 5
    start "C:\Users\pasi1\Desktop\Minecraft Sachen\MultiMc\Java Installs\jdk-17.0.3+7\bin\java.exe" %%A
)`

This is what I tried from another post on stackoverflow but didn't work out. I am trying to execute this via a batch file on windows

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be automatic like it is for batch files, JavaScript, and others.

1. You need to modify the PATHEXT environment variable and add .jar to the list.  Once you look at the list, the rest should be self explanatory.  This change will allow windows to execute a file using association.  Unless there is ambiguity in a file name, you can even skip the .jar extension after this change.  Be aware, this is opening up the possibility for something else (bad actor) to run .jar files too.. but no different than .bat or .exe even.
2. The registry needs to contain a file association for .jar files with an "open" verb.  This should already be done by the JRE installer I assume but I don't run Java much so I don't know for sure if this is a feature of the installer.  This is also required for the `start` method mentioned by the @Hannu excellent answer.

Once you modify the PATHEXT environment and start a NEW console, you should simply be able to execute the .jar file as if it were an executable.  In *nix, this is done via SHEBANG at the beginning of a file `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/perl` or whatever.. but the windows mechanism is very different (as described above).

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that i should make it integrated into windows that jar files will be open with java? Normally that is the case if you install Java, but in my case I want this to be portable without having to install java in windows internally.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a "portable" solution to this without specifying the command line to java.exe or "jury rigging" it through your environment with (for instance) a batch file or something that you call to launch it however you like.

Comment: Perhaps some genius will come along and give a better option.  You should update your question with your intent so some guru can have the AHA! moment you have yet to see.

Comment: Well my solution right now works. Java is installed so to say but not internally. I can reinstall windows this way and still have Java as long as its in that folder, just internal functions like opeing a .jar file won't work. The only thing I want to improve is that the .jar file opens without me having to go into the batch-file and renaming the file to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never installed Java, but only have it as part of another
installed product, the following might work (or not):

- Run a Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Enter the following commands :

  ```
  assoc .jar=jarfile
  ftype jarfile="C:\Users\pasi1\Desktop\Minecraft Sachen\MultiMc\Java Installs\jdk-17.0.3+7\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*
  ```

Following this, a double-click in Explorer on a `.jar` file will open
the file using the specified `java.exe`.

If after this it still doesn't work, it might mean the the `java.exe` that
you found cannot work stand-alone, but only in the context of Minecraft.

Comment: Okay so I just tried this and it doesn't change anything. It doesn't even change the file accosciaten for my .jar file.

Comment: What is the current association?